# How to cleanly disable Grub after a migration to systemd-boot?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, bootloader, systemd-boot

Short story: I replaced `grub2` with `systemd-boot` and cannot be happier. Much simpler, and works perfectly on a rather complex efi multi-boot system mixing sata, nvme...

Now I want to make sure `update-grub` and friends are not going to be called and mess with the config when a new kernel is apt installed.

There are many posts about removing / uninstalling Grub... but in my case

```
# apt --simulate purge grub2-common
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  grub2-common*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc-12-base:i386 grub2-common:i386 krb5-locales libc6:i386 ...
```

and many other 32 bits packages are to be installed.

There is probably a 32 bits package that requires all that (and was happy with grub2-common)? How can I find it if that's the case?

And anyway, is there a way to cleanly remove `grub` or at least disable it, without installing a bunch of 32 bits packages?

Comment: Have you tried trying to remove it via aptitude? It sounds like there is a conflict and apt is showing you the first solution it found. Aptitude will show what all those solutions are and what is causing the conflict

Comment: Same thing. Aptitude says it will install 26 packages i386 ; it says that `shim-signed` depends on grub2-common - not sure I can remove shim-signed (as well)...

Comment: Ahh I see. `shim-signed` is what is preventing you from removing grub2. This package is the bootloader that boots the bootloader during secure-boot. If you have secure boot w/ Microsoft keys, you need this (I don't know if systemd-boot also uses shim or is signed separately). For more info see https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface/Secure_Boot

Answer (score 1):

Boot from another media and mount the root partition of your system.

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Then chroot into the mounted partition so that you can execute commands as if you were logged into the installed system

```
chroot /mnt
```

Then remove grub.

```
apt-get remove grub2
```

Finally unmount and reboot your system.

*** Don't forget to backup your data before doing this ***